# FrameLayout inside a GridView as an Item

Tags: android, gridview, android-framelayout

Is it possible to have a `FrameLayout` as an item for the `GridView`? like this :

[image]

each square is an item, and each item is composed of a `FrameLayout`. If this is possible, how? ive been trying to search the net for hours but i cant find any helpful solution. Please help thank you :)

Comment: Yes, sure. Just use a custom adapter for binding up the data to the views defined in your own item layout. Plenty of examples out there.

Comment: But i cant find any? can you link some? @MH.

Comment: Just Google for something like ["android custom arrayadapter"](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+custom+arrayadaptyer) and you'll get a plethora of examples. Make sure to reference one that applies the ViewHolder/RowWrapper pattern. For example, [this one](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive) (which has quite a lot of useful reading material too).